# Theme Check warning wrong direcory for theme

Tags: themes

I am checking my theme with theme check and it is raising following warning:

> WARNING: Your theme appears to be in the wrong directory for the theme
>   name. The directory name must match the slug of the theme. This
>   theme's correct slug and text-domain is prisma. (If this is a child
>   theme, you can ignore this error.)

Although page slug I have used is prisma and also tried to rename the WordPress installation directory to prisma but still the error is persisting.
Can anybody guide me how to resolve the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your theme directory name. it usually resides here:

```
/wp-content/themes/
```

then check if your theme name and directory name matches. you can change it in your computer or FTP client easily. if through terminal, use this command:

```
$ sudo mv -v OLDDIRECTORY NEWDIRECTORY
```